# Aggregate value takes very long time

Tags: c#

I have one big list of 15 min values for oround year. and I would like to aggregate them into hours. I am doing it in very simple way :

```
for (; from <= to; from = from.AddHours(1))
{
    List<DataPoint> valuesToAgregate = data.Where(x => x.TimeStamp >= from && x.TimeStamp < from.AddHours(1)).ToList();
    dailyInputData.Add(valuesToAgregate.Sum(x=>x.Val));

}
```

This way it takes a lot of time, like 30 seconds for 35k of values, is there any way to optimize it ? maybe use ordering functionality or some how add index to list or using grouping by instead of for loop?

Comment: Do you really need the temporary `List<DataPoint>` instance?

Comment: does it make huge differnce ? this is simplify logic, I pass this list into other method. but the problem is data.Where(x => x.TimeStamp >= from && x.TimeStamp < from.AddHours(1)).ToList(); thsi takes time

Comment: @kosnkov That makes difference, You're creating an array in every loop. not only that you're looping the sequence twice(one with `ToList` another with `Sum`)

Comment: Further optimizations may be possible, but I would start trying to omit that temporary list. Yes, it can make a difference; you are allocating a `List<DataPoint>` and adding a subset of `data` when you do not really require any list. If you just want to break up your selection command into several lines, declare `valuesToAgregate` as `IEnumerable<DataPoint>` and omit the `ToList()` call - you will have the same simplification (in terms of readability), but the subset will not be saved in between; it will be lazily evaluated.

Comment: Another detail you could optimize is that currently, you call `from.AddHours(1)` for every item (in your lambda expression passed to `Where` rather than storing the result in a variable and then using that in the lambda expression. The compiler will probably not optimize that on its own, as it does not know whether each call to `from.AddHours(1)` returns the same value for a given `from`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, if you order your list by TimeStamp previously, this will work quicker. Example:

```
var orderedData = data.OrderBy(item => item.TimeStamp).ToList();
int firstIndex = 0;
var from = orderedData.First().TimeStamp;
var to = orderedData.Last().TimeStamp;
while (from < to)
{
    var sum = 0;
    var newTo = from.AddHours(1);
    while (firstIndex < data.Count && orderedData[firstIndex].TimeStamp < newTo)
    {
        sum += orderedData[firstIndex].Val;
        ++firstIndex;
    }
    dailyInputData.Add(sum);
    from = from.AddHours(1);
 }
```

Comment: instead of using `.Count()` method you could just use `Count` property of `List<T>`, ofcourse this can be used if the data type is `List<T>` or `IList<T>`

Comment: @Selman22, yes, you're right, thanx. If `data` is not `IList<T>`, we could use `orderedData` and get `Count` of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = data.Sort(x=>x.TimeStamp);
int counter = 0;
var boundary = from.AddHours(1);
foreach(var d in data){
    if(d.TimeStamp > boundary){
        boundary = boundary.AddHours(1);
        counter = 0;
        dailyInputData.Add(counter);
    }
    ++counter;
}
```

This problem lies in the logic

1. the list is scanned from start to end every time to find the candidate values (your where clause)
2. the candidate values are inserted to another temp list
3. the temp list is THEN scanned from start to end to calculate the sum

The fastest approach:

1. sort the list
2. go through the items, if they belong to the current group, add the counter, otherwise you've jumped to a new group, flush the counter to record the value and start it over again